# MySQL ORDER BY conditional second

Tags: mysql

Selecting from a table `events` including columns `start_date` and `ongoing` (boolean), I would like to:

1. Sort results **first** by `ongoing` (all 0s before 1s).
2. **Then** I would like to sub-sort all *non-ongoing* events (`ongoing = 0`) by `start_date ASC` and all *ongoing* events (`ongoing = 1`) by `start_date DESC`. I'm probably missing something stupid simple (maybe using `CASE`?), but I'm stuck!

TIA

Comment: You would have to use a calculated value (and generate it differently for `0` and `1` respectively to create a value that would order). I suspect this would be slower than just running two separate queries.

Comment: could you provide data samples and expected result please? sqlfiddle wold be very helpful

Comment: Show us what you've got so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just calculate using `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
...
ORDER BY ongoing, IF(ongoing, TIMESTAMPDIFF(NOW(), start_date), 
                              TIMESTAMPDIFF(start_date, NOW()))
```

Note how the order of the arguments is reversed in the 2 cases. (I may have them reversed myself - if so, just swap them in each call.)

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to figure out how to put `ASC` and `DESC` inside a conditional. I changed function to `DATEDIFF` for my purposes (using `DATE` data type), but this did the trick!